# Switch position of elements in the footer

Tags: php, html, footer

I am new to Wordpress and I was wondering is there a possibility to customize a theme I got, to my desires.

My footer has two content areas, one for the copyright content and one for the social links. The copyright content is on the left side, the social links on the right.

I wish to change the copyright to the right and the social links to the left.

I was trying to change the php files so the social icons will be included first and then the copyright section. But now I am stuck. Where can I just switch the php includes for this 2 items.
Could anyone please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using Flexbox. Add the following CSS code somewhere in your theme stylesheet or via dashboard `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`

```
.fusion-copyright-content {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
}

.fusion-copyright-content .fusion-social-links-footer {
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the answer I waas looking for.